# Group an array of objects by unix time while filtering on nested values

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

I'm dealing with OpenWeather API. My goal is to display the date and a timetable if that date (at any given time stamp) has windspeed >= MIN_WIND_SPEED

**Edit: Added input and expected output JSON**

The object returned from the API looks like this:

```json
[
  {
    "dt": 1632808800,
    "wind": {
      "speed": 3.5
    }
  },
  {
    "dt": 1632819600,
    "wind": {
      "speed": 3.53
    }
  },
  {
    "dt": 1632830400,
    "wind": {
      "speed": 3.05
    }
  },
  {
    "dt": 1632841200,
    "wind": {
      "speed": 1.64
    }
  },
  {
    "dt": 1632852000,
    "wind": {
      "speed": 2.39
    }
  },
  {
    "dt": 1632862800,
    "wind": {
      "speed": 3.19
    }
  },
  {
    "dt": 1632873600,
    "wind": {
      "speed": 4.03
    }
  },
  {
    "dt": 1632884400,
    "wind": {
      "speed": 4.67
    }
  },
  {
    "dt": 1632895200,
    "wind": {
      "speed": 3.93
    }
  },
  {
    "dt": 1632906000,
    "wind": {
      "speed": 5.02
    }
  },
  {
    "dt": 1632916800,
    "wind": {
      "speed": 4.86
    }
  },
  {
    "dt": 1632927600,
    "wind": {
      "speed": 3.73
    }
  },
  {
    "dt": 1632938400,
    "wind": {
      "speed": 2.99
    }
  },
  {
    "dt": 1632949200,
    "wind": {
      "speed": 3.31
    }
  },
  {
    "dt": 1632960000,
    "wind": {
      "speed": 4.29
    }
  },
  {
    "dt": 1632970800,
    "wind": {
      "speed": 5.14
    }
  },
  {
    "dt": 1632981600,
    "wind": {
      "speed": 5.86
    }
  },
  {
    "dt": 1632992400,
    "wind": {
      "speed": 6.5
    }
  },
  {
    "dt": 1633003200,
    "wind": {
      "speed": 5.81
    }
  },
  {
    "dt": 1633014000,
    "wind": {
      "speed": 6.58
    }
  },
  {
    "dt": 1633024800,
    "wind": {
      "speed": 4.98
    }
  }
//...
]
```

I want to convert it into an object like this:

```json
[
  {
    "key": "Saturday 09/25",
    "value": [
      {
        "dt": 1632808800,
        "wind": {
          "speed": 3.5
        }
      },
      {
        "dt": 1632819600,
        "wind": {
          "speed": 3.53
        }
      },
      {
        "dt": 1632830400,
        "wind": {
          "speed": 3.05
        }
      },
      {
        "dt": 1632841200,
        "wind": {
          "speed": 1.64
        }
      },
      {
        "dt": 1632852000,
        "wind": {
          "speed": 2.39
        }
      },
      {
        "dt": 1632862800,
        "wind": {
          "speed": 3.19
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "Sunday 09/26",
    "value": [
      {
        "dt": 1632808800,
        "wind": {
          "speed": 3.5
        }
      },
      {
        "dt": 1632819600,
        "wind": {
          "speed": 3.53
        }
      },
      {
        "dt": 1632830400,
        "wind": {
          "speed": 3.05
        }
      },
      {
        "dt": 1632841200,
        "wind": {
          "speed": 1.64
        }
      },
      {
        "dt": 1632852000,
        "wind": {
          "speed": 2.39
        }
      },
      {
        "dt": 1632862800,
        "wind": {
          "speed": 3.19
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "Monday 09/27",
    "value": [
      {
        "dt": 1632808800,
        "wind": {
          "speed": 3.5
        }
      },
      {
        "dt": 1632819600,
        "wind": {
          "speed": 3.53
        }
      },
      {
        "dt": 1632830400,
        "wind": {
          "speed": 3.05
        }
      },
      {
        "dt": 1632841200,
        "wind": {
          "speed": 1.64
        }
      },
      {
        "dt": 1632852000,
        "wind": {
          "speed": 2.39
        }
      },
      {
        "dt": 1632862800,
        "wind": {
          "speed": 3.19
        }
      }
    ]
  }
//...
]
```

The logic should convert `dt` into `dddd MM/DD` and group all the `dt` of the same day together with `key` being the date in human readable. It should also remove dates that does not have wind >= MIN_WIND_SPEED

I'm trying with these functions to filter the timestamp that has `wind.speed` >= MIN_WIND_SPEED and group the entries by key `dt`

```js
const list = weatherList.filter((i) => i.wind.speed >= MIN_WIND_SPEED);

const groupByDay = () =>
  list.reduce((entryMap, entry) => {
    let selector = unix(entry.dt).format("dddd MM/DD");

    return entryMap.set(selector, [...(entryMap.get(selector) || []), entry]);
  }, new Map());
```

This method removes all of the time stamps that does not have wind.speed >= MIN_WIND_SPEED. The results have the correct dates but the dates are missing the timestamps with `wind.speed` < MIN_WIND_SPEED.

**Current UI:**
[image]

**Expected UI:**
[image]

In this example, Saturday and Sunday should NOT be displayed! Because thay don't have any timestamp that has wind >= MIN_WIND_SPEED

Thanks!

Comment: The question is not very clear. Share the input JSON, explain how should the output should look like (based on the input) and explain the logic that should translate input to output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a 'group-by' followed by a [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to only include groups that have at least one element that meets your condition.

Here accumulating into an object using `reduce()`, formatting the date using [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat), and then calling [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) on each group's value array to `filter()` the groups.

```js
const input = [{ dt: 1632808800, wind: { speed: 3.5 }, }, { dt: 1632819600, wind: { speed: 3.53 }, }, { dt: 1632830400, wind: { speed: 3.05 }, }, { dt: 1632841200, wind: { speed: 1.64 }, }, { dt: 1632852000, wind: { speed: 2.39 }, }, { dt: 1632862800, wind: { speed: 3.19 }, }, { dt: 1632873600, wind: { speed: 4.03 }, }, { dt: 1632884400, wind: { speed: 4.67 }, }, { dt: 1632895200, wind: { speed: 3.93 }, }, { dt: 1632906000, wind: { speed: 5.02 }, }, { dt: 1632916800, wind: { speed: 4.86 }, }, { dt: 1632927600, wind: { speed: 3.73 }, }, { dt: 1632938400, wind: { speed: 2.99 }, }, { dt: 1632949200, wind: { speed: 3.31 }, }, { dt: 1632960000, wind: { speed: 4.29 }, }, { dt: 1632970800, wind: { speed: 5.14 }, }, { dt: 1632981600, wind: { speed: 5.86 }, }, { dt: 1632992400, wind: { speed: 6.5 }, }, { dt: 1633003200, wind: { speed: 5.81 }, }, { dt: 1633014000, wind: { speed: 6.58 }, }, { dt: 1633024800, wind: { speed: 4.98 }, },];

const MIN_WIND_SPEED = 6;

const result = Object.values(
  input.reduce((a, o) => {
    const date_string = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('default', {
      weekday: 'long',
      month: '2-digit',
      day: '2-digit',
    }).format(new Date(o.dt * 1000));

    (a[date_string] ??= { key: date_string, value: [] }).value.push({ ...o });

    return a;
  }, {})
).filter((g) => g.value.some((o) => o.wind.speed >= MIN_WIND_SPEED));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Alternatively you could pull the date formatting out into its own helper function and build a `Map` which only has keys for days that meet the MIN criteria while at the same time creating a temporary array with formatted date_string props to each object. You can then iterate over the temp array and accumulate into the [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), and finally return an array using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) called on the result of the reduce. Here using two [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loops.

```js
const input = [{ dt: 1632808800, wind: { speed: 3.5 }, }, { dt: 1632819600, wind: { speed: 3.53 }, }, { dt: 1632830400, wind: { speed: 3.05 }, }, { dt: 1632841200, wind: { speed: 1.64 }, }, { dt: 1632852000, wind: { speed: 2.39 }, }, { dt: 1632862800, wind: { speed: 3.19 }, }, { dt: 1632873600, wind: { speed: 4.03 }, }, { dt: 1632884400, wind: { speed: 4.67 }, }, { dt: 1632895200, wind: { speed: 3.93 }, }, { dt: 1632906000, wind: { speed: 5.02 }, }, { dt: 1632916800, wind: { speed: 4.86 }, }, { dt: 1632927600, wind: { speed: 3.73 }, }, { dt: 1632938400, wind: { speed: 2.99 }, }, { dt: 1632949200, wind: { speed: 3.31 }, }, { dt: 1632960000, wind: { speed: 4.29 }, }, { dt: 1632970800, wind: { speed: 5.14 }, }, { dt: 1632981600, wind: { speed: 5.86 }, }, { dt: 1632992400, wind: { speed: 6.5 }, }, { dt: 1633003200, wind: { speed: 5.81 }, }, { dt: 1633014000, wind: { speed: 6.58 }, }, { dt: 1633024800, wind: { speed: 4.98 }, },];

const format_date = (dt) =>
  new Intl.DateTimeFormat('default', {
    weekday: 'long',
    month: '2-digit',
    day: '2-digit',
  }).format(new Date(dt * 1000));

const MIN_WIND_SPEED = 6;

const map = new Map();
const temp = [];

// format date_strings & build Map
for (const o of input) {
  const ds = format_date(o.dt);
  if (o.wind.speed >= MIN_WIND_SPEED) {
    map.set(ds, []);
  }
  temp.push({ ds, ...o });
}

// reduce
for (const { ds, ...o } of temp) {
  if (map.has(ds)) {
    map.get(ds).push(o);
  }
}

// convert Map to result array
const result = Array.from(map, ([key, value]) => ({ key, value }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Edit:** Edited to meet clarified logic in the comments. Because an entire data group should be returned if any of the elements meet the `MIN_WIND_SPEED` cutoff, you'll need to run the full 'group-by' and then `filter()` groups based on whether they meet the requirements. Here using [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: Im still getting the output with only the hours that is >= MIN_WIND_SPEED. The condition is if a date has at least one hour that >= MIN_WIND_SPEED, then the whole date forecast (all its timestamp) is included in the output object.

Comment: Edited to meet your requirements. You'll need to filter *after* reducing as there's no clear way to know if another element in the same group might fulfill the criteria ahead of time.

Comment: Thank you it finally worked! The condition is pretty unusual and it took me quite a while to form a clear and concise question. Appreciate the effort!

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just but the boolean check inside the reduce function? If it doesn't pass, just return the map? I added a snippet below without the date formatting as it functions the same.

*Edit*: Added date formatting, not the same way you're doing it, but I believe this is the result you're after. Let me know if I'm wrong.

*Edit 2*: Updated the code snippet. The date key isn't exactly what you want, but I have to make dinner :P

```js
const speeds = [{
    "dt": 1632808800,
    "wind": {
      "speed": 3.5
    }
  },
  {
    "dt": 1432819600,
    "wind": {
      "speed": 3.53
    }
  },
  {
    "dt": 1632830400,
    "wind": {
      "speed": 3.05
    }
  },
  {
    "dt": 1632841200,
    "wind": {
      "speed": 1.64
    }
  }
]

const groupWindSpeedsByDay = (windSpeeds, minWindSpeed) => {
  const grouped = windSpeeds.reduce((map, windSpeed) => {
    if (windSpeed.wind.speed > minWindSpeed) {
      const date = new Date()
      date.setMilliseconds(windSpeed.dt)
      const selector = `${date.toString().split(' ')[0]} ${date.getMonth() + 1}/${date.getDate()}`;
      map[selector] = map[selector] ? [...(map[selector]), windSpeed] : [windSpeed];
    }

    return map
  }, {});

  return Object.keys(grouped).map(key => ({
    key: key,
    values: grouped[key]
  }));
}

console.log(groupWindSpeedsByDay(speeds, 3))
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but the output only contains the timestamp with wind.speed > 9. They also need to include the entire timestamp of that day. I edited my question with the expected output JSON. Maybe you can have a look gain? Thanks!